# Using "Equals" for valuetypes in C# seems not a good idea, is it?

Tags: c#, equality, value-type

I red that the default behavior for "Equals" in value types (structs) is using reflection to compare the content of the two values, so it's recommended to override the Equals operator for efficiency if performance is important.

But it seems that the signature of Equals is :

```
public override bool Equals( object ob )
```

Which means that even if i'll override this method, i'll still have boxing when i compare value type because the parameter must be of an "object" type.

Am i correct ? is boxing does occur ? 
Should i use only == operator for value type ?

EDIT : 
And a little side question, why when i override == it should be static and get 2 parameters instead of the more intuitive form of not being static and comparing "this" with one parameter ?

Comment: Reflection only occurs if there are reference types in the struct. Otherwise a byte-by-byte comparison is done in memory.

Comment: Gather performance metrics before overriding `Equals`, override `Equals`, gather performance metrics again.  Pick which ever is faster.  If you need to do something other than a bit-wise comparison of the memory occupied by the struct, then always override `Equals`--performance doesn't matter if something is not correct.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to overriding `Object.Equals()` you should implement `IEquatable<T>`, where `T` is your type itself.  `IEquatable<T>.Equals()` accepts an argument of type `T`.

If you implement the interface implicitly (and why wouldn't you?) then the more specific method accepting the `T`-typed argument will be used when possible, and in this case no boxing will occur.  (This is true if you overload `Equals()` and don't implement the interface, but there is no reason not to implement the interface in this case.)

This is the pattern I usually use when implementing value type equality:

```
struct Foo : IEquatable<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo other)
    {
        // Do your equality test here.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other != null && other is Foo) {
            return Equals((Foo)other);
        }

        return false;
    }

    // If you also want to overload the equality operator:
    public static bool operator==(Foo a, Foo b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator!=(Foo a, Foo b)
    {
        return !a.Equals(b);
    }
}
```

Of course, don't forget to override `Object.GetHashCode()` too.

---

Note that when using the `Equals(object)` method, only the argument is boxed.  The object you are invoking on will *not* be boxed, unless you convert it to `object` (or an interface type) first.  One of the `ldloca`, `ldflda`, or `ldsflda` instructions will be emitted (as appropriate) for the object you invoke on, and the other would be boxed (in the absence of a more-specific overload).